# Why does yarn work but node or tsc fails?

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, openai-api

I am trying to learn (I only know Python) the OpenAI API with TypeScript via LiteLLM. I found some examples like

(openai.ts)

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';


const openai = new OpenAI({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
  apiKey: "not-needed",
  })
  
async function main() {
  const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'what year are we in' }],
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
  });
    console.log(chatCompletion.choices[0].message.content);
}


main();
```

My problem is that `yarn tsc` compiles with no errors but `node run` throws lots of errors:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Typescript\_tests_\run'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

`tsc src\openai.ts` returns errors:

```
tsc src\openai.ts
node_modules/openai/core.d.ts:135:5 - error TS18028: Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.

135     #private;
        ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/openai/lib/AbstractChatCompletionRunner.d.ts:14:5 - error TS18028: Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.

14     #private;
       ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/openai/lib/ChatCompletionStream.d.ts:13:5 - error TS18028: Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.

13     #private;
       ~~~~~~~~


Found 3 errors in 3 files.

Errors  Files
     1  node_modules/openai/core.d.ts:135
     1  node_modules/openai/lib/AbstractChatCompletionRunner.d.ts:14
     1  node_modules/openai/lib/ChatCompletionStream.d.ts:13
```

Why am I getting three different results with this? Why don't they just compile like yarn does? Why does yarn compile while tsc fails? I really do not understand.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of tsc by updating node to it's latest version. OpenAI requires tsc 4.5 at the least. Latest now is is 5.3.3
You also need a rather new ECMA Script, I think at least 2015. I had the same problem in vs code and solved it by replacing the target version in tsconfig.json this way "target": "es2017",

Comment: I have this "target": "es2017", and it still complaints  "Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher."  TSC 5.3.3